# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried using a package called wikipedia (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/)
and when I run the following code:

```
import wikipedia

print wikipedia.search("Barack Obama")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\wiki.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wikipedia
  File "C:\Users\barkayshahar\Documents\Programming\AI\wikipedia.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have any files in your current working directory named `wikipedia.py`, delete or rename them.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.